# File object gets set to string even with with ContentType false

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I am trying to pass the File object to controller HttpPostedFileBase variable, but can't bind it properly.

Javascript ajax call:

```
var formData = new FormData();

var _documents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++) {
    var document = {
        File: arrayOfFiles[i].file,
        DocumentId: arrayOfFiles[i].documentId,
        DocumentType: arrayOfFiles[i].documentName
    };

    _documents.push(document);
    formData.append("file", document.File);
    formData.append("id", 146);
}

jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")',
    data: formData
});
```

MVC controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("UploadFile")]
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<int> id, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
{
    var aa = Request.Form.Get("file");
    return View();
}
```

`aa` gets a string "[object Object]", `id` gets a list containing 146 and `file` get an empty array.

How to properly send File object so it would get binded with `file`?

Comment: Are you sure `arrayOfFiles` contain actual instances of the File object. I'd check `document.File instanceof File` to see if it was indeed a file

Comment: @Musa I did not know about this keyword before. Thank you for telling me about it. Apparently it is not a File object, but an Object object. Any ideas how I could fix it?

Comment: Do a `console.log(document.File)` and look through the object for the file.

Comment: @Musa It had nativeFile property, which was that file. I am very grateful for your suggestions